# Swipe to Refresh spinner sometimes hidden by headers

Tags: bug, android-app

Seems to be a bug the first time you launch the app where the refresh icon gets hidden by the section headers until the device is rotated.

Fresh launch:

> [image: First Run]

After rotation:

> [image: After Rotation]

It also reappears after you scroll another header into view. I'm guessing the headers are getting brought to the front and end up in front of the swipe refresh view.

Comment: Seems the issue was mitigated since the arrival of Hot Network Question on the feed ([v1.0.69](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260498/app-keeps-crashing-rendering-error-since-update-to-1-0-68#comment851160_260498)): having section header on the top is now impossible due to HNQ, and to refresh, you have to go to the very top, which is the HNQ again.