# App keeps crashing & rendering error since update to 1.0.68

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I can reproduce that every time now, I go to a site, open an article, then to the next site, open another article. The `Feed` page pops up for a second, the article page lays over this with some some transparent areas (see picture). The same app-version is ok on a Smartphone with Android 4.4.2. I also sent in some bug reports.

[image: Screenshot of smashed page]

**Edit**

<strike>1.0.71 isn't the solution yet. I go to Meta SE, then to an article. When I want back to Meta SE again, it crashes. Much earlier than before. I already sent in a bug report for this.</strike>

**Another Edit**

<strike>I can describe it better now. From the questions-page of a site I go to a post. When I use the back button, everything is ok, I can go to the next site. When I try to go to the next site directly from the post, it crashes. This only happens on the Nexus 10 with Android 5.1.1, App version 1.0.71. Hope this helps.</strike>

**Edit<sup>3</sup>**

This is fixed in 1.0.73 now. Thanks again.

Comment: Just want to confirm [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260464/android-app-crashes-when-opening-the-user-page-on-xiaomi-mi-tablet?lq=1), will it crash if you open your user profile from the app?

Comment: @AndrewT. No, the profile page is shown correctly.

Comment: I could also see this issue randomly on my Xiaomi MI tablet. App crashes intermittently.

Comment: Happens to me on my Azpen A727 with Android 4.2.2.  Reverted to the prior version and it works just fine.

Comment: It happens exacly as @ott-- described on my tablet. I can read the first site all I like, but going to another site and opening one article, boom.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Same tablet, [same bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260541/266359)

Comment: @ott-- what tablet are you using?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Google Nexus 10 with Android 5.1.1

Comment: Repro'd, working on a fix now.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi That's good news at the end of the day.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi any update? Or has the bug won the battle? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have a fix, I'm waiting until I finish a new feature (hot questions in feed on phones) before I release it.

Comment: Cheers @Kasra, that's good to hear. While at it... are there any plans to add revisions list in the android app same as iOS app got for a while now? Personally that's the most useful missing part in the app for me.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have lots of plans for catching up to Brian -- The diff view of the revisions list took him weeks, it'll probably take me months :\

Comment: @Kasra hmm... and no shortcuts? Or getting Brian to move sides? ;)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi The new version still keeps crashing, see my edit.

Comment: @Kasra and finally looks like it's fixed. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

I'm so happy to report this is fixed now. We pretty much redid the entire backbone of the app and this god forsaken rendering issue should no longer happen again.