# Bug in display of question

Tags: bug, android-app

I don't think this is how questions are supposed to look in the Android app...

[image: screenshot of the SE Android app displaying a question with pieces of the feed mixed in]

Android 4.2.2, app version 1.0.68 (which I believe is the most current)