# Bug report android app overlay list and post

Tags: bug, android-app

this happened after the app was called using a broadcast intend

**version 1.0.71** (Google play newest)

[image]

Comment: What version of the app do you have?

Comment: using 1.0.71. and it is a duplicate. sorry for that

Comment: I'm not sure it is a duplicate; the other question mentions 1.0.68 specifically. I was gonna let others have a look at it, see how they vote.

Comment: I interpreted the "Edit

1.0.71 isn't the solution yet.

" as duplicate

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that part of that question. I haven't used 1.0.71 much yet, so [I don't know if it's been fixed yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260541/266359)