# Android app 1.0.77 has a multi-view transparency bug on tablet

Tags: bug, android-app

This is only for the Android tablet with App version 1.0.77. I couldn't reproduce that on the smartphone.

The App starts on the Feed page. Use the icons on the left in the following order:

1. Site 1
2. User profile
3. Feed
4. Site 1
5. Site 2

You end up on a view like this:

[image: level 2]

Do it once more and then

[image: level 2]

I even managed to get up to level 3:

[image: level 3]

Comment: Confirmed. I see the same behaviour

Comment: [regression?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260498/app-keeps-crashing-rendering-error-since-update-to-1-0-68) :(

Comment: I see the same on 1.0.78 on my Nexus 7 Second Gen (2013) with Android 6.0.1.